How do I convert a string column of GMT-3 to a datetime column in EST in Python?
I have a column that's currently an object type and in GMT-3 timezone as pictured below:

I know I can easily call pd.to_datetime() on this, but how would I convert this to EST?
Here's a list of the values if this helps:
['8:00PM GMT-3', '9:00PM GMT-3', '11:00PM GMT-3', '11:00PM GMT-3',
       '9:00PM GMT-3', '11:00PM GMT-3', '8:00PM GMT-3', '8:30PM GMT-3',
       '10:30PM GMT-3', '2:00PM GMT-3']

Thanks so much.

df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df.datetime, format="mixed").dt.tz_convert(tz="US/Eastern")

be aware that you cannot set a timezone to a time only since timezone rules depend on date and time. So make sure to specify an adequate date first.

You can first localize to GMT-3 (using 'Etc/GMT+3) and then convert to EST by considering EST as 'America/New_York':
import pandas as pd

times = ['8:00PM GMT-3', '9:00PM GMT-3', '11:00PM GMT-3', '11:00PM GMT-3',
         '9:00PM GMT-3', '11:00PM GMT-3', '8:00PM GMT-3', '8:30PM GMT-3',
         '10:30PM GMT-3', '2:00PM GMT-3']

times_dt = pd.to_datetime(times, format='%I:%M%p GMT-3', errors='coerce')

times_dt_localized = times_dt.tz_localize('Etc/GMT+3')

times_est = times_dt_localized.tz_convert('America/New_York')

times_est


Which will give you
DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-01 18:04:00-04:56', '1900-01-01 19:04:00-04:56',
               '1900-01-01 21:04:00-04:56', '1900-01-01 21:04:00-04:56',
               '1900-01-01 19:04:00-04:56', '1900-01-01 21:04:00-04:56',
               '1900-01-01 18:04:00-04:56', '1900-01-01 18:34:00-04:56',
               '1900-01-01 20:34:00-04:56', '1900-01-01 12:04:00-04:56'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', freq=None)

However, you can see there is an offset of -04:56, which is LMT. That is caused by the date inserted by default, 1900-01-01 (as was pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/fobersteiner) . Hence, you should specify a specific date
import pandas as pd

times = ['8:00PM', '9:00PM', '11:00PM', '11:00PM',
         '9:00PM', '11:00PM', '8:00PM', '8:30PM',
         '10:30PM', '2:00PM']

base_date = '2024-04-10 '
times_with_base_date = [base_date + time for time in times]
times_dt = pd.to_datetime(times_with_base_date, format='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p', errors='coerce')
times_dt_localized = times_dt.tz_localize('Etc/GMT+3')
times_est = times_dt_localized.tz_convert('America/New_York')
times_est_str = times_est.strftime('%I:%M%p').tolist()

print(times_est)

which gives
DatetimeIndex(['2024-04-10 19:00:00-04:00', '2024-04-10 20:00:00-04:00',
               '2024-04-10 22:00:00-04:00', '2024-04-10 22:00:00-04:00',
               '2024-04-10 20:00:00-04:00', '2024-04-10 22:00:00-04:00',
               '2024-04-10 19:00:00-04:00', '2024-04-10 19:30:00-04:00',
               '2024-04-10 21:30:00-04:00', '2024-04-10 13:00:00-04:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', freq=None)


note that in your output, you get a UTC offset of -04:56, which is LMT. That is caused by the date inserted by default, 1900-01-01. See also my comment on the OP.

@FObersteiner Good observation there! Making an addition to my solution.
